# Printing star patterns using recursion is showing an extra line

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printPattern(int n);

int main() {
    int n =4;    
    printPattern(n);
    return 0;
}

void printPattern(int n){
    if (n=1){
        printf("*\n");
        return;
    }

    printPattern(n-1);

    for(int i=0;i< (2*n-1);i++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Here, the value of n is 4 so in void function if statement shouldn't work because n is not equal to 1 and it will not print `*`, but if you run the code it will print `*` and I don't know why. The n value is 4 so it should skip that if statement and then n value will become 3 because of `printPattern(n-1)` and then it will print 1-3-5 stars in 1-2-3rd lines

```
*   
*** 
*****
```

But if you run the code it will print 1-3-5-7 stars in 1-2-3-4th lines

```
*  
***  
*****  
*******
```

The loop occurs after the recursion so it should print 3 lines (1-3-5 stars) instead of 4 lines (1-3-5-7 stars) also here in this code, if statement is used without else.

I was learning to print odd number of star per line in increasing order using recursion from Youtube, can anybody explain this to me.

Comment: if (n=1) should be changed to if (n==1). consider using an IDE to test and debug your code.

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Oh didn't notice this mistake, thx for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(n=1)` or `( n==1)`
**your program is all okay! just a tiny mistake :p**